# Search context in robot framework

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

In selenium Java, we can find an element with an element by `findElement(locator1).findElement(locator2)`
Also we can do
`DefaultElementLocatorFactory locatorFactory = new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(getElement()); PageFactory.initElements(locatorFactory, this);`
Q1. How can we achieve the same thing in robot framework ?
Q2. How can we achieve the same thing in python ?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/672

There is no inbuilt function , but you can use:

Create a keyword

```
  Get child element
```

it takes two argument parent(Webelement) and child(Xpath) to search for child inside the parent.

```
  Get child element    ${parent}    ./h3
```

Assuming parent xpath to as : `//ul[@id="top_menu"]` , the above code will search for equalent xpath `//ul[@id="top_menu"]/./h3` note taht context is parent and not root

so this will be equalent to xpath

```
*** Test Cases ***
Google Search
    [Tags]    you    probably    do    not    have    this    many    tags    in    real    life
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  CSS=[id="introduction-container"]
    ${parent}=    Get webelement    xpath=//*[@id="introduction-container"]
    ${result}=    Get child element    ${parent}    ./h3   
        
    
*** Keywords ***
Get child element 
    [Arguments]    ${parent}   ${child} 
    ${child}=    Execute Javascript    return window.document.evaluate( arguments[1], arguments[0], null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;     ARGUMENTS    ${parent}    ${child}
    [Return]    ${child}
```

Comment: sorry to get back late. I tried however got the below error
`${child}=    Execute Javascript    return window.document.evaluate( arguments[1], arguments[0], null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;    ARGUMENTS    //section[contains(@class, 'tabContent active oneConsoleTab')]//section[contains(@class, 'tabContent active oneConsoleTab')]    //h1/div[contains(text(), 'Case')]`

JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': parameter 2 is not of type 
'Node'.